# Variance of $\frac{X_i}{\theta^2} -\frac{1}{\theta}$ in an exponential distribution

Tags: variance, exponential-distribution

I read in a book discussing the exponential distribution that the variance of  $\frac{X_i}{\theta^2} -\frac{1}{\theta}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{\theta^4}Var(X_i) = \frac{1}{\theta^4}\theta^2$. **Can someone please explain how $Var(X_i) = \theta^2$?**

Note: It was also given in the book that $X_i$ is a random sample from an exponential distribution with pdf $f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta} \exp^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exponential distribution has mean $\theta$ and variance $\theta^2$.

If X has variance $\sigma$, then $(aX+b)$ has variance $a^2  σ$. This means, $b$ just translates the distribution but doesn't affect its variance, it just changes its mean.

The same can be applied in your case.

Comment: Isn't the variance of the exponential distribution $\frac{1}{\theta^2}$ instead of $\theta^2$? For instance, see: https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/exponential-distribution

Comment: It depends how you use the parameter of the exponential in the PDF. He is using 1/θ as the rate, λ. The mean and variance of exponential is 1/λ and 1/λ^2. This is, θ and θ^2 in his case.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And sorry for saying "he is using"  and "his case". I mean, you :)